# UIView - Subview contents aren't redrawn until subviews are laid out again. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am adding some subviews to my view controller's root view in the `viewDidLoad` method. Soon after, when a particular event occurs, I am simply changing the background color on one of the views. This change isn't visible until the subviews are laid out again (`willLayoutSubviews` gets called) This happens either if I change the orientation of the device or wait 10-20 seconds. I am calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the subview right after making the change, but it is not helping.

To summarize, I'm simply trying to change the background color of a subview after a certain event occurs, and I'd like the changes to be visible on screen within maybe a second or so. What am I missing?

Note: In case it matters, the superview of the view in question is a `GLKView`.

Comment: Are you doing these updates from a background thread by chance?

Comment: Come to think of it, I am doing these updates in a delegate method callback which is, in fact, running in an async dispatch queue. I am now using `performSelectorOnMainThread` to ensure that the updates are performed in the main thread. Feel free to add a response as an answer, and I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are only making UI updates from the main thread.  You can fix this by using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` or `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{/* your UI modifying code here */});`.

Comment: I am using `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` and it's working as expected now.